# Visual SVN Server Backup Restore Error (vnadmin: E140001: Malformed dumpfile header)

Tags: php, svn, phpstorm, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I am trying to Restore the SVN dump that i took before refreshing the Windows, Now  i created the New Repository and trying to restore the backup from that Dump file but i am getting this Error.

```
vnadmin: E140001: Malformed dumpfile header
```

Here is the Command which i am using to Restore the Backup.

```
svnadmin load --ignore-uuid C:\Repositories\Zorkif > D:\My_SVN_Dumps\zorkif_new-7-5-2013.svn
```

Thanks to `ÁlvaroG.Vicario`
He solved one Problem but still New Problem showed up.

```
svnadmin: E160020 : File already exists: filesystem 'C:\Repositories\Zorkif\db', transaction '1-2', path 'branches'
```

its a New Repository, Then why i am getting this Problem?

Comment: `>` redirects the **output**. You've destroyed your dump. Do you have a backup copy?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario
Yes i have backup copy.
i know it destroys the dump file :(
From `141,498kb` it goes to `0kb` whenever i run this command, so i again copy paste the file from my external Harddrive to this folder :(

What to Do?

Comment: You can find the correct syntax in [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario
Sorry, but i am not getting how it works?
How to implement it in my Scenario??

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario
Many Many Thanks Sir.
My Mistake, i used `>` instead of `<` But now after changing it i am getting new Problem.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario
I updated my question, and posted the error i am getting.